# getting error in selecting checkbox , containing multiple Image

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am working in Angular 7 Application , 
I have selected one Image on verious other Images ,

for that I have used checkbox on each Images but I am facing problem

As Image is coming from service , and we are itating on each Image  so problem is starting here on selection of Image

Problems -:

1. **when we are selecting one Image every Image is selected**
2. **we are not getting Id of the Iamge on selection of the Image**

I am putting code for it -:

html -:

```
  <div *ngFor="let img of Images">
   <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" [(ngModel)]="img.id" (change)='getId(img.id)' />
      <label for="cb1"><img src="{{img.photo}}" /></label>
    </li>

  </ul>
  </div>
```

ts -:

```
   Images: any;
      UserPhoto: any;
      getavator(){

        this.rest.avatarList('Bearer ' +this.token).then(res => {
          if(res['status'] == 1){
            this.Images = res['data'];
            console.log(this.Images);
          } })
      }
      select(value){
        console.log(value);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set unique `id` for input checkbox and label `for` attribute. By this way you can prevent the selection of all checkbox when selecting a checkbox.

```
  <div *ngFor="let img of Images">
   <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="{{img.id}}" [(ngModel)]="img.id" (change)='getId(img.id)' />
      <label for="{{img.id}}"><img src="{{img.photo}}" /></label>
    </li>

  </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to capture the id could be like this:

`(click)=getId($event.target.id)`, if this does not work, just try with '&event' and see what kind of data it gives you with a console.log.
And I believe the problem with every image clicking is that all of them have the same ID, that is beacuse you put an element with 'id' inside an `*ngFor`, and you should not do that.